# Contract Call from another Contract

Tags: solidity, remix

I am trying to refer to this Solidity Docs https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.2/control-structures.html and trying to execute the following code

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.7.0;

contract InfoFeed {
    function info() public payable returns (uint ret) { return 42; }
}

contract Consumer {
    InfoFeed feed;
    function setFeed(InfoFeed addr) public { feed = addr; }
    function callFeed() public { feed.info{value: 10, gas: 800}(); }
}
```

I am getting the following error

Expected ';' but got '{'
    function callFeed() public { feed.info{value: 10, gas: 800}(); } after info

This is the current version of docs and didnot expect to get this errors. Thank you for the help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect for any older compiler. It looks like it works only for version 0.6.2 and beyond.

Here's the right syntax for the line with any not-the-latest-compiler:

```
feed.info.value(10).gas(800)();
```

Typically you don't want to specify and special gas limit for an internal transaction so just leave that part out and it will just use whatever gas is left.

Also I strongly recommend to indent your code properly. It helps for readability and for detecting errors. So here's the indented version:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.7.0;

contract InfoFeed {
    function info() public payable returns (uint ret) { 
        return 42;
    }
}

contract Consumer {
    InfoFeed feed;
    function setFeed(InfoFeed addr) public { 
        feed = addr;             
    }
    function callFeed() public { 
        feed.info.value(10).gas(800)();             
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. It seems that the syntax I posted only works for compliers with 6.2+ commits only. So is there a way to send gas with such contract calls or they are not recommended. I really want to send the gas value with the call if it is possible

Comment: I wasn't even aware of the brand new syntax, thanks for the heads-up! You can provide the same data with the syntax I gave you. Edited answer.

Comment: Yes, it works great. I was just curious if is there a way to send gas value with function calls or not

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. You can supply the amount of gas in the old syntax with `.gas(number)` as I stated in my answer. If you don't provide that argument then all remaining gas is forwarded.

Comment: Ah, I see. My bad. Sorry for the trouble. So I believe the receiving function must be payable in order to send a gas value

Comment: No, it must be payable to send value. Gas can be forwarded to any function.

Comment: Awesome, makes sense and everything is clear. Thank you for the help and knowledge